# Gatsby - Nestled Component Not Rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Sorry if there's a really simple solution, but building websites isn't my area of expertise.

I'm currently trying to create a Gatsby website where I have a Component nestled inside another Component but it shows a completely blank screen when I try to show the nestled Component. Following the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65190163/gatsby-doesnt-render-components), I implemented a `Layout` Component that serves as a template for every site. In the future, I plan to tidy up the navigation bar and implement that into the `Layout` Component, but that's an issue for another time.

I'm currently trying to put in a `Tile` Component into my `Layout` that is also encapsulated inside my `IndexPage`, but my screen just shows nothing when I try to run it. I've tried to shorten the code so that it includes the minimum amount required.

I've taken a look at the [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/building-with-components/) and it appears that under the ["Non-page components"](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/building-with-components/#non-page-components) section that I should use GraphQL, which I'm not sure how it works.

I suspect that the reason why it isn't working is that the `Tile` Component has to take in an `imgLocation`, `altText`, and `caption` properties, and somewhere along the way the code isn't working as intended.

---

Code:

index.js:

```js
import * as React from "react"
import Layout from './Layout.js';
import Tile from './Tile.js';

// markup
const IndexPage = () => {

    return (
        <Layout pageTitle="Home">
                <div id="main">
                    <div className="inner">
                        <h1>
                            <b>Portfolio</b>
                        </h1>
                        <p>
                            Here's all of the work that I've been commissioned to do over the past few years.
                        </p>
                        <h2>
                            <b>Christmas</b>
                        </h2>
                        <h3>
                            <b>Portrait</b>
                        </h3>
                        <section className="tiles">
                            <Tile imgLocation="imageFileLocationGoesHere" altText="descriptionOfImage" caption="Image Description" />
                            <Tile imgLocation="imageFileLocationGoesHere" altText="descriptionOfImage" caption="Image Description" />
                        </section>
                        <br />
                        <h3>
                            <b>Landscape</b>
                        </h3>
                        <section className="tiles">
                            <Tile imgLocation="imageFileLocationGoesHere" altText="descriptionOfImage" caption="Image Description" />
                            <Tile imgLocation="imageFileLocationGoesHere" altText="descriptionOfImage" caption="Image Description" />
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* Footer */}
                <footer id="footer">
                    {/* footer goes here */}
                </footer>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default IndexPage;
```

Tile.js (within the same folder as index.js):

```js
import React from "react";
import '../css/main.css';

const Tile = (props) => {
    const imgLocation = props.imgLocation;
    const altText = props.altText;
    const caption = props.caption;

    return (
        <article>
            <span>
                <img src={require({imgLocation}).default} alt={altText} onClick={() => {openModal(props)}} />
            </span>
            <br />
            <p>{caption}</p>
        </article>
    );
}

export default Tile;
```

Layout.js (within the same folder as in index.js)

```js
import * as React from 'react';

const Layout = ({pageTitle, children}) => {
    return (
        <main>
                <title>{pageTitle}</title>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <meta
                    name="viewport"
                    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
                />
                {children}
        </main>
    )
}

export default Layout;
```

Comment: "...but it shows a completely blank screen when I try to show the nestled Component" - is there an error in the console? Do you do anything before it shows a blank page? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Brendan Bond In the console there are multiple errors that say, "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '[object Object]'". Let me know if you want more info. It's happening in the Tile.js file, specifically where I use the `img` object.

Comment: Ha yes, more info is definitely needed. What line is the error throwing on? What's up with the src attribute in the image tag having a `require` function? You're also passing the string `"imageFileLocationGoesHere"` as a prop? Lots of problems here, this is why people typically ask for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there's just too much going on here to try and help without a lot more context.

Comment: Yes, OK, let's start there (your most recent comment edit). Why do you have `require({imgLocation}).default` as the src attribute in that img tag?

Comment: @Brendan Bond I have multiple different images, so depending on what is passed in the `imgLocation`, I want to be able to find it there. Oh, and `"imageFileLocationGoesHere"` isn't the actual string being used, in reality it would actually be an actual location like "./images/img.png".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing here is that your `Tile` component is inside the `/pages` folder as you pointed here:

> `Tile.js` (within the same folder as `index.js`):

So, Gatsby is trying to create a page based on the `Tile` component, hence, you are trying to render a page inside a page.

Move your component into another folder such as `src/components/Tile` and the issue should be gone.

`Layout` component also needs to be outside `/pages` folder.

Regarding the image, try to import it in the parent component and lift it to the child like:

```
import * as React from "react"
import Layout from './Layout.js';
import Tile from './Tile.js';

... 

<Tile imgLocation={'./path/to/your/image.png'} />
```

And then:

```
  <img src={imgLocation} alt={altText} onClick={() => {openModal(props)}} />
```

Or even drilling the image directly:

```
    import Img from './path/to/your/image.png'

   ...

    <Tile img={Img} />
```

Then:

```
const Tile = ({img:Img, altText, caption}) => {

    return (
        <article>
            <span>
            <Img />
            </span>
            <br />
            <p>{caption}</p>
        </article>
    );
}

export default Tile;
```

Reassigning the `img` props as React component should also do the trick

Comment: So I did that and it still gave me the "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '[object Object]".

Comment: Try removing CSS modules (to see if the issue is there). They need to be imported namely  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66869576/gatsby-warn-attempted-import-error-css-does-not-contain-a-default-export-i/66869722#66869722

Comment: The problem is that I never use the CSS module in my `Tile` component so it shouldn't affect it at all. I'll probably stylize it later, but that's not what's causing my issue. I even removed the line `import '../css/main.css'` in my Tile.js file and it didn't change.

Comment: `require({imgLocation}).default` that line is weird. Import it as ES module (`import X from '../../imgLocation`)

Comment: The problem is that I can't import it inside of the `Tile` component itself, and I want the `imgLocation` to be a variable so that I can create different `Tile`s with different images.

Comment: Yep, but first you need to fix your blank page, afterwards you can move forward the image importation. Does this fix the blank rendering? I'd try a dynamic import instead a require

Comment: Now I have a Module parse failed: Unexpected character. I've tried doing `var url = require('.../images/test.PNG).default;` as well as directly importing it like `import img from '../images/test.PNG';` like from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458511/how-to-use-es6-import-for-images). It still gives me a blank screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240665/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-perplexingparadox).